# need help finding a closed form function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help to find a function in closed form "not a power series" for: $\sum_{k\geq2} k(k-1)z^k$.

I am not quite sure how to start the problem, i tried using the derivative but that did not work out.

Comment: What exactly did you do with the derivative?  That should work if you do it the right way.

Comment: ok i said summation k>=2. k(k-1)z^k=(d/dz)(summation kz^(k-1))

Comment: Hint:  Write $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)z^k = z^2\sum_{k=2}^\infty k(k-1)z^{k-2}$$

Comment: So you need to work out $\sum kz^{k-1}$. . . use the same trick again.  Also there is a minor slip in what you just wrote in your comment, you will need to find it and fix it.  But the basic idea is right.

Answer (score 1):

First convince yourself that
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k\tag{1}
$$
for $|z|<1$ (I'm sure there are hundreds of proofs of this on this site). Differentiating both sides of (1) gives 
$$
\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k z^{k-1}
$$
Can you use this idea to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k\ge 2} k(k-1)z^k = z^2\sum_{k\ge 2} k(k-1)z^{k-2} = z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\sum_{k\ge0} z^k = z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{1}{1-z}.
$$
So when you find the second derivative, you're done.

Comment: That should be $\frac{1}{1-z}$ in that last line.

Comment: Typo fixed. ${}\qquad{}$